# 2022 Apple Mac Studio M1 Max w/ dual displays 4K@144 Hz

Tags: display, thunderbolt, displayport

I just received a 2022 Mac Studio M1 Max, additionally I purchased a Thunderbolt 3 to dual DisplayPort 1.4 adapter: [OWC Thunderbolt Dual DisplayPort Adapter](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/TB3ADP2DPT/)

When attempting to connect both displays, the first one connected will take 144 Hz, while the second is capped at 95 Hz. I verified both monitors ([LG GN950](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27gn950-b-gaming-monitor)) support 4K 144 and the cables support DisplayPort 1.4 DSC by connecting to my gaming PC w/ a 3080RTX.

Lastly I ordered Thunderbolt 3->DisplayPort cables to check if it's just the adapter that doesn't work. However, input from anyone with experience would be much appreciated.

One more thing: [Macs and 4K 120 Hz displays compatibility list](https://tonsky.me/blog/monitors-mac/)

Someone shared that they have an M1 Ultra w/ 2x 4K displays at 144 Hz, but no detailed config information

Mac Studio (M1 Ultra, 2022)

2 × Gigabyte M32U (4K @ 144 Hz)

Answer (score 1):

So the adapter does not work, and it makes sense as I believe the bandwidth for dual 4K displays at 144 Hz exceeds that of TB4. I simply ordered the USB-C -> DisplayPort adapters and everything works as expected.

[image: Screenshot of System Info]